# Using sed to search multiple strings in XML file

Tags: shell, sed, xml

I need to filter a big file XML and find the string using a multiple conditions.
I need a filter a email if cnisfCF equal true and natg_passwordAlreadyResetedPostMigration is true.

Anyone can help ?

```
<customer customer-no="09090909090">
        <credentials>
            <login>teste@gmail.com</login>
            <enabled-flag>true</enabled-flag>
            <password-question/>
            <password-answer/>
        </credentials>
        <profile>
            <salutation/>
            <title/>
            <first-name>teste</first-name>
            <second-name/>
            <last-name>name 1</last-name>
            <suffix/>
            <company-name/>
            <job-title/>
            <email>teste@gmail.com</email>
            <phone-home>542926407485</phone-home>
            <phone-business/>
            <phone-mobile/>
            <fax/>
            <birthday>1999-09-12Z</birthday>
            <gender>2</gender>
            <creation-date>2022-09-19T18:34:45.000Z</creation-date>
            <preferred-locale/>
            <custom-attributes>
                <custom-attribute attribute-id="natg_Newsletter">false</custom-attribute>
                <custom-attribute attribute-id="natg_cfIsCn">false</custom-attribute>
                <custom-attribute attribute-id="natg_cpf">5465465456456</custom-attribute>
                <custom-attribute attribute-id="natg_infContOptIn">false</custom-attribute>
                <custom-attribute attribute-id="natg_optInWP">false</custom-attribute>
                <custom-attribute attribute-id="natg_passwordAlreadyResetedPostMigration">true</custom-attribute>
                <custom-attribute attribute-id="natg_personNumber">116864397</custom-attribute>
                <custom-attribute attribute-id="natg_pushOptIn">false</custom-attribute>
                <custom-attribute attribute-id="natg_rut">456456456</custom-attribute>
            </custom-attributes>
        </profile>
```

Comment: Not exactly a proper answer, but you can start reading here:
https://www.baeldung.com/linux/evaluate-xpath

Comment: Please [edit] your question and i) add the output you need from this example input. Do you want the email as output? Valid XML as output? Do you want to keep emails matching the conditions or remove them? We can't tell without the expected output. ii) please provide a _valid_ XML input example if you are working with XML.

Comment: Regarding comment above by WhiteOwl - using an XML capable tool is the right starting point - trying to parse xml with sed is a really bad idea.

Comment: There is no `cnisfCF` in the example so it can never be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've taken the liberty to add the missing `</customer>` closing tag in the data before test-running the below commands and to assume that you by `cnisfCF` meant `natg_cfIsCn` (attribute and node names are case-sensitive).

---

Using `xmlastarlet`:

```bash
xmlstarlet select --template \
    --match '//profile' \
    --match 'self::node()[custom-attributes/custom-attribute[@attribute-id="natg_cfIsCn"]="true"]' \
    --match 'self::node()[custom-attributes/custom-attribute[@attribute-id="natg_passwordAlreadyResetedPostMigration"]="true"]' \
    --value-of 'email' -nl file.xml
```

The above command would extract the value of the `email` node in any `profile` node in the input document that has `custom-attributes/custom-attribute` child nodes with `attribute-id` attributes `natg_cfIsCn` and `natg_passwordAlreadyResetedPostMigration` and values `false` and `true`, respectively.

The tricky thing here is to present the command in a readable way since the names of the nodes involved in the paths are so long. I solved this by first matching the `//profile` path and then doing two separate steps of narrowing down the result set from there.

The select statement using only a singular "value-of" XPath query would look like

```bash
xmlstarlet select --template \
    --value-of '//profile[
        custom-attributes/custom-attribute[@attribute-id="natg_cfIsCn"]="true" and 
        custom-attributes/custom-attribute[@attribute-id="natg_passwordAlreadyResetedPostMigration"]="true"
    ]/email' -nl file.xml
```

If this looks prettier, then use that instead.  They should be equivalent, I believe.

Note that the above commands do not produce any output for the given document, as there is no data matching the queries.